# How do I select the rows of a table that don't match another table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to display all the names from the table `vocabulary` where the `vid`s do not match a `vid` in `collapse_menu`. How would I do this?

```
Table vocabulary
    vid     name
    1   Sections
    2   Posts
    6   Forums
    5   Departments
    13  Free Tags
    8   Committees
    9   Training and Workshops
    10  Policies
    12  Projects
    14  Teams

Table collapse_menu
vid
8
5
10
```

Comment: Please learn the art of 'Descriptive Title Fu'. It will aide you in your travels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select name from vocubulary where vid not in (select vid from collapse_menu)

Comment: or use "WHERE NOT EXIST( subselect )"

Answer (score 13):

I assume that you are asking for the those names in vocabulary, where the vid is not in the collapse_menu table.

In which case

```
SELECT name
FROM vocabulary
LEFT JOIN collapse_menu ON vocabulary.vid = collapse_menu.vid
WHERE collapse_menu.vid IS NULL
```

Comment: Bingo. Some of the other suggestions will work for a simple situation, but this is the technique to remember for complex cases.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Same technique is useful when calculating "grouped maxima", that is, for each group return the max value. Then, by definition of max value, we can turn the problem into "exclude everything that has have a bigger value == take everything that doesn't have a bigger value" by left joining the table with itself and et voila'.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM vocabulary, collapse_menu WHERE vocabulary.vid <> collapse_menu.vid;

Answer (score -2):

```
select name 
from vocabulary as v, 
     collapse_menu as c 
where v.vid!=c.vid
```

Edit: Sorry, didn't read the question properly.